# Real time Communication over 3g (PC -> Android Smartphone -> Arduino)

Tags: android, arduino, 3g

I'm developing an Arduino project (but this is not important). For this project I need to communicate (radio control) to my Arduino  from my PC. The idea is to send the message or the instruction to my smartphone (cheap Android), which is connected to the internet over 3g. Then the phone will communicate to Arduino thank to the audio port (jack audio), sending a frequency controlled pulse, that is quite easy to do.

The problem is the **communication between the PC and the smartphone**.
Somebody has an idea of how to achieve that, eventually creating a simple application, or better, directly from the opened smartphone browser (android froyo 2.2)?

Which is the best server technology to use, and the faster, considering the tipical 3g ping?I haven`t found any source on the web, so I hope in your answers.

Comment: You will probably end up having to use an intermediate server on the public Internet at least for the initial connection setup, as the mobile provider will not permit incoming connections to the phone, and configuring a typical residential ISP & router setup feeding a consumer PC fo that to accept outside connections is tricky and preferably avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The microcontroller can be, with Wifly and this firmware  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101922388/WiflySanUSB.zip , a server (switching the led signal through 192.168.1.195/YT in adress bar) or also a client (the AD converter value is inserted in google databank).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could solve your problem: htpp://www.muzzley.com

1. Download C#/java sdk/nodejs and build your app in your computer (and connect it to arduino has you would like)
   http://www.muzzley.com/downloads
2. Build your own widget to run on the side of the smartphone through this widget: http://www.muzzley.com/documentation/widgets/webview.html

note: you do not need to worry about the smartphone app. It's already done. Just build your own interface

**How it will work**

[SMARTPHONE 3g/4G]  ---> [Computer with app] ---> arduino

I hope it helps.